# How should I use const in the grammar below?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, macos, dart

I'm studying platters by myself. When I enter the code like below, it says to use const grammar like the attached picture, how can I add it without errors?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crEoB.png)

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title; //
  MyHomePage({required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          title,
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // child: Image.asset('images/tree.jpg'),
        child: Text(
          'Hello, Text Widget',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 25,
            color: Colors.purple,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please give me answer bro...
I'm begginner

Comment: it is warring/suggestion message for better practice , you can add const before center

Answer (score 1):

It is just warring/suggestion message for better practice , you can add `const` before center

```dart
body: const Center(
  // child: Image.asset('images/tree.jpg'),
  child: Text(
    'Hello, Text Widget',
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 25,
      color: Colors.purple,
    ),
  ),
),
```

But if you read something inside the Center widget, it cant be const.

[Find more about dart](https://dart.dev/language).

Answer (score 0):

do this way,

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title; //
  MyHomePage({required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          title,
        ),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        // child: Image.asset('images/tree.jpg'),
        child: Text(
          'Hello, Text Widget',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 25,
            color: Colors.purple,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

or

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title; //
  MyHomePage({required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          title,
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // child: Image.asset('images/tree.jpg'),
        child: const Text(
          'Hello, Text Widget',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 25,
            color: Colors.purple,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good practise to use const keyword, when you know, it not going to change during compile time. In your case add it in Center() widget .